# MacOS mdfind/mdutil issue and updatedb command : how to index all the files on my /Volume (root /)

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, spotlight, zsh

A simple question : on Linux, `updatedb` command which is launched a second time seems not to reindex all the hard disk.

On MacOS Catalina (or maybe for previous), it seems that the command `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` reindexes all.

Is there an option for locate.updatedb to only update what's new ?

I thought about doing : `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb -u` but I am not sure.

`mdfind` is a great tool but has got no transparency about its dameons `mds`  : I said this since suddenly on my MacOS, `mdfind` stopped finding recent files, and it was very frustrating. Moreover,  it takes a long time to index all the Volume (several days in my case, 2TB HD).

So I wonder if `locate.updatedb` command that updates from what is already existing is possible ?

On Linux systems, where updatedb is performed, this command is very quick because the whole database is no reindexed.

I just want not to reindex all the /Volume at each time I launch `locate.updatedb` on MaOS.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have killed all `mds` and processes relaled to `mdutil` and `mdfind`. Then, I launched yesteray a :

`mdutil -E /` :

here what I get when I do a `ps aux | grep mds` :

`$ psu | grep mds
root              9607   0.0  0.9 11835260 285804   ??  Ss    9:20PM   2:14.29 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mds_stores
root              9606   0.0  0.2  6866808  71984   ??  Ss    9:20PM   5:27.05 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds` .

I don't understand why it doesn't return all files which normally should be found : example with `mdfind -name README`, it only return a partial of the expected result (nothing is displayed into my $HOME).

Moreover, the loop glass on right top indicates that indexing is fully carried out but from my opinion, this is too fast, I have 1.2TB of data of index : is it normal, what do you think about this ?

Any suggestion/explanation is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The `updatedb` program on macOS is a very different program than the `updatedb` program on Linux. In contrast to the Linux program, the macOS program does not attempt to reuse existing database data about directories that haven't changed.

There's no option for the macOS program that will make it behave like the Linux program.

Comment: @jksoegarrd So how to control or check the progress of indexing on MacOS with `mdfind` tool ? I don't know when indexation is finished, it seems to take a lot of time (several days on my 2 TB hard disk), what are exactly the daemons which runs and index ? `mdfind` is not transparent at all. You will really help me if you can answer to these different questions  or some of them. Recently, I lost the main utility of `mdfind` when recent files created were no more found, and it was very frustrating.

Comment: Click the "looking glass" icon in the top right corner of your desktop. It will show you indexing status when indexing is in progress.

Comment: Regarding daemons - the mds daemon is responsible for the functionality - it receives events when files and folders are changed, deleted or added. It spawns mdworker processes which then update the index with those changes.

Comment: If you feel the indexing process has gone haywire, you can use the following guide to rebuild the index: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

Comment: I would prefer lauching the reindexing from terminal command line. Is it the following command right on MacOS Catalina : `cd / ; mdutil -E /` ? I saw it might be necessary ,before, to delete DS_store or V100 files but I didn't find these files on my root `/`.

Comment: Well, the first part of the command serves no purpose... but yes "mdutil -E /" would delete the metadata database on the root volume (i.e. note that this is NOT a path, but rather you're specifying a volume - so if you have multiple disks, make a note of this).

Comment: If you're interesting in what you can do more specifically, run "man mdutil" to read about it.

Comment: I have killed all mds and processes relaled to mdutil and mdfind. Then, I launched yesteray a `mdutil -E /` : here what I get when I do a `ps aux | grep mds` : `psu | grep mds
root              9607   0.0  0.9 11835260 285804   ??  Ss    9:20PM   2:14.29 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mds_stores
root              9606   0.0  0.2  6866808  71984   ??  Ss    9:20PM   5:27.05 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds` .

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't return all files which normally should be found : example with `mdfind -name README`, it only return a partial of the expected result (nothing is displayed into my $HOME).

Comment: Why did you kill mds and the processes? - Why are you running the ps command? (I know what it does, but I'm asking why you're running it). I.e. you come with the objective to reindex, and I tell you how to do it - but now you're doing unrelated stuff. Why?

Comment: Did you reindex before using mdfind? -- Have you checked in System Preferences => Spotlight that you haven't excluded your home folder from the index?

Comment: @jkoegaard. I just wanted to rebuild all the index and that's why I have erased all the existing data index by doing a `mdutil -E`. Is it correct to do this ?

Comment: Yes, it is literally what I told you to do a few comments back?  ... But remember to run it on all your volumes/drives. I.e. on a modern system you'll probably have a seperate system volume from the user data volume.